# Binding the width of a control in visualstatemanager

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, visualstatemanager

Is it possible to bind the width of a control to the width of another control using visualstatemanager ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you saying that on a Visual State you want to change the Width Dependency Property to something like `{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SomeOtherControl}` ? Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi Chris,Thanks is exactly what i meant. not sure if its legal to do that in visualstatemanager. btw any idea if binding even to a property in allowed inside visualstatemanager?

Comment: Hmm this is one of those questions I'd have to go test myself to see. Not sure if it would raise the propertychanged event or anything to change the already rendered object. I would say give it a shot and post results because I'm a bit curious also and I don't recall trying it myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ObjectAnimationUsingKeyframes to set a binding in the VSM.  Something like:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SomeControl"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Duration="Forever" >
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" >
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Binding ... />
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value> 
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```